# Закрытие окна из ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

Какие есть варианты закрытия окна из ViewModel. Смог придумать только такой:

```
 public class LoginViewModel
    {
        private LoginWindow loginWindow;
        public LoginViewModel(LoginWindow _login)
        {
            loginWindow = _login;
        }
        private void CloseWindow()
        {
            loginWindow.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Так же делаю, не вижу в этом особой проблемы.

Comment: Хотелось бы чтобы ViewModel не получала ссылку на View.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, кстати.

Comment: @VladD, буду рад услышать Ваш вариант)

Comment: @Lightness: Держите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейший вариант — привязать `Window.Visibility` к свойству VM.

Будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmWindowOpenClose.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <!-- тонкость: вам нужно определить конвертер перед привязкой,
         поэтому Visibility="{Binding ...}" не скомпилируется -->
    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="B2V"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Visibility>
        <Binding Path="IsPresented" Converter="{StaticResource B2V}"/>
    </Window.Visibility>
    <Grid>
        <!-- остальной код окна -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Нам нужна простая VM-ка:

```
class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool isPresented = false;
    public bool IsPresented
    {
        get { return isPresented; }
        set { if (isPresented != value) { isPresented = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }
    }

    public async Task Run()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        IsPresented = true;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        IsPresented = false;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    // реализацию INPC по идее нужно вынести в базовый класс
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Из `App.xaml` уберите `StartupUri` (т. к. мы запускаем VM, а не View). В `App.xaml.cs` положите следующее:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    MainWindow window;
    MainVM vm = new MainVM();

    public App()
    {
        window = new MainWindow() { DataContext = vm };
    }

    protected override async void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        await vm.Run();
        Shutdown(0);
    }
}
```

Voilà, вы управляете видимостью из VM без прямой связи и без особенной магии.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы используете MVVM Light, то можете из ViewModel отправить сообщение:

```
          Messenger.Default.Send<CloseViewMessage>(new CloseViewMessage());
```

В конструкторе окна регистрируете событие для сообщения:

```
   Messenger.Default.Register<CloseViewMessage>(
          this,
            (msg) =>
            {
               this.Close();
            });
```